# Loading spinner is not working on ng-click or ng-change in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using a loading spinner while loading a page.

```
App.controller('MailFolderController', ['$scope', '$http',function ($scope, $http){
$scope.loading = true;

    $scope.allotmentStatus = [
    {"value": "", "text": "All"},
    {"value": "ALLOTTED", "text": "ALLOTTED"},
    {"value": "UNALLOTTED", "text": "UNALLOTTED"}
    ];

    $http.get(serverUrl).then(function (result) {
        $scope.itemList = result;
    });

    $scope.changeItemList = function () {
      $scope.loading = true;
      $http.get(newServerUrl).then(function (result) {
          $scope.itemList = result;
          $scope.loading = false;
          });
    }

    $scope.changeItemListAccordingToStatus = function (alotment) {
         $scope.loading = true;
         $http.get(newServerUrl+'?alotment='+alotment).then(function (result) {
                $scope.itemList = result;
                $scope.loading = false;
              });
     };

     // Other functions
     $scope.loading = false;
]}
```

And in view page :

```
 <div ng-controller="ItemsController">
     <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="changeItemList()"> Check New Items </button>

    <select id="allotmentStatus" data-ng-model="allotment" ng-options="c.text for c in allotmentStatus"                                                            ng-change="changeItemListAccordingToStatus(allotment.value)"></select>


        <table>
            <img src="app/img/spinner.gif" ng-show="loading"/>
           <tr ng-repeat="item in itemList">
               <td>{{item.name}}</td>
               <td>{{item.quentity}}</td>
               <td>{{item.status}}<td>
           </tr>
        </table>
 </div>
```

Loading spinner is working fine when page load first time, But when I click on button and change value of select tag the value of list are changing according to API call, But the loading spinner is not working. (ng-click is used in button click, and ng-change is used in Select tag)

Any suggestion will be appreciable . Thank you

Comment: On click it is visible or not ?

Comment: no, loading spinner is not visible , after click on  button , or not visible while ng-changes

Comment: provide id to <img> and then use angular.element('#loader').show() and angular.element('#loader').hide() . I had same problem and it resolved it

Comment: Hi @Shubham , I have add id="loader" in the image tag , still its not showing spinner image. And other suggestions ?

Comment: any error in console??

Comment: nop , there are no error message in console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84537/discussion-between-shubham-nigam-and-naren-mehta).

Answer (score 1):

Use another variable as we have discussed earlier because your variable may got reflected from another places.

```
App.controller('MailFolderController', ['$scope', '$http',function ($scope, $http){
//$scope.loading = true;

    $scope.allotmentStatus = [
    {"value": "", "text": "All"},
    {"value": "ALLOTTED", "text": "ALLOTTED"},
    {"value": "UNALLOTTED", "text": "UNALLOTTED"}
    ];

    $http.get(serverUrl).then(function (result) {
        $scope.itemList = result;
    });

    $scope.changeItemList = function () {
      $scope.loadingSpinner = true;
      $http.get(newServerUrl).then(function (result) {
          $scope.itemList = result;
          $scope.loadingSpinner = false;
          });
    }

    $scope.changeItemListAccordingToStatus = function (alotment) {
         $scope.loadingSpinner = true;
         $http.get(newServerUrl+'?alotment='+alotment).then(function (result) {
                $scope.itemList = result;
                $scope.loadingSpinner = false;
              });
     };

     // Other functions
     $scope.loadingSpinner = false;
]}
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="ItemsController">
     <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="changeItemList()"> Check New Items </button>

    <select id="allotmentStatus" data-ng-model="allotment" ng-options="c.text for c in allotmentStatus"                                                            ng-change="changeItemListAccordingToStatus(allotment.value)"></select>


        <table>
            <img src="app/img/spinner.gif" ng-show="loadingSpinner"/>
           <tr ng-repeat="item in itemList">
               <td>{{item.name}}</td>
               <td>{{item.quentity}}</td>
               <td>{{item.status}}<td>
           </tr>
        </table>
 </div>
```

Comment: I have used $scope.loading = false; many times, thats the only reason, its not showing the spinner.  Thanks @Shubham,  after changing the variable name its working fine, Now my problem is solved.